# Reading file names in path and writing on JSON file

Tags: c#

I have a file directory in `C:Data\` like

[image]

How can I write on an existing JSON file called `Offline.json` to be like:

```
{
"GDB":[ "C:Data/GDB/GDB1.gdb",
        "C:Data/GDB/GDB2.gdb", 
        "C:Data/GDB/GDB3.gdb" 
       ],
"TPK":[ "C:Data/TPK/TPK1.gdb",
        "C:Data/TPK/TPK2.gdb"
       ],
"MPK":[ "C:Data/MPK/MPK1.mpk",
        "C:Data/MPK/MPK2.mpk", 
        "C:Data/MPK/MPK3.mpk",
        "C:Data/MPK/MPK4.mpk",
        "C:Data/MPK/MPK5.mpk", 
        "C:Data/MPK/MPK6.mpk" 
       ]
}
```

on loading the WPF main windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) this is kinda easy to accomplish:

```
// Your main code...
String path = @"C:\Data\";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
String json = GetJsonDirectoryStructure(di).ToString();

// Method implementation...
public static JObject GetJsonDirectoryStructure(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    JObject jObj = new JObject();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo diChild in di.GetDirectories())
        jObj.Add(diChild.Name, GetJsonDirectoryStructure(diChild));

    foreach (FileInfo di in di.GetFiles())
        jObj.Add(fi.Name, JValue.CreateNull());

    return jObj;
}
```